# How can I detect the scrollTop of an element using Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, scrolltop

I want to add a class to an element when the user scrolls more than 100px from the top of the element but I seem to be triggering this as soon as the page loads. This is the code that I have at the moment

```
const content = document.getElementById("content");
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  content.classList.add(
    'curtain-in',
    content.scrollTop > 100
  );
});
```

Also with your answer can you please explain where I've gone wrong.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe what is happening is that `content.scrollTop` is always returning `0` and your condition is never fulfilled. I've struggled myself with that problem trying to make a fiddle to test your case.

To check if the scroll has passed the beginning of the element plus 100px  we need to know where the element starts and the new position of the scroll, we can get both values like this:

```
var position = content.offsetTop;
var scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
```

With these, you can do something like this in your event function:

```
const content = document.getElementById("content");
document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {

  var scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  var position = content.offsetTop;

  if(scrolled > position + 100){
    content.classList.add(
      'curtain-in');
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvmw3L1o/1/

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add a class to an **element** when the user **scrolls** more than
>   100px from the **top of the element**

You should add `addEventListener` to `content` not `document`

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");
content.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  console.log('class added');
  content.classList.add(
    'curtain-in',
    content.scrollTop >= 100
  );
});
```

```css
#content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

p {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: use Throttling for performance https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes sense, and code snippet works but now the class isn't being added at all on my page, no errors in the console either. Have added console.log like you have to see when the event is triggered. I replaced const content = document.getElementById("content");
content.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  console.log('class added');
  content.classList.add(
    'curtain-in',
  );
});

with "click" and that works, but the event isn't triggering on the scroll
was wondering if you knew why

Comment: @Jessica On the other pages, you have same element with same `ID` ? `content` ? if not you should use `class`. After all, it should work on other page too, every page that contain `content` element.

Comment: I only have 1 element with the id of content

Comment: @Jessica So what do you expect? you asked when you scroll on `#content` element, so it should work just on this element, no matter where it is, should work on all page if you have that element.